# related initializing remo after installation ,for building image-annotation-web-app

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pip, initialization

i had installed it through :
`pip install remo`
then i tried to initialize it through :
`python -m remo_app init`
but an error is showing of installing postgres even after installing it manually
i also tried with different versions but in vain
the error was:

```
C:\Users\Admin>python -m remo_app init

===============================================
((
(>’:’) Remo: v0.4.5
Python: 3.8.1, Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0

Initiailizing Remo:

This will download and install the following packages as needed:

vips
postgres
scoop
git
unzip
aria2
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]: y
[-] Installing vips lib

[-] Installing postgres
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py”, line 193, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File “C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py”, line 86, in run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\remo_app_main.py", line 3, in
app()
File “C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\typer\main.py”, line 211, in call
return get_command(self)()
File “C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\click\core.py”, line 829, in call
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File “C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\click\core.py”, line 782, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File “C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\click\core.py”, line 1259, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File “C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\click\core.py”, line 1066, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File “C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\click\core.py”, line 610, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File “C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\typer\main.py”, line 494, in wrapper
return callback(**use_params) # type: ignore
File “C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\remo_app\cmd\cmd.py”, line 55, in init
db_config = installer.install(postgres=postgres.get_instance())
File “C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\remo_app\cmd\installer.py”, line 333, in install
return postgres.install()
File “C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\remo_app\cmd\installer.py”, line 212, in install
if not self._is_installed():
File “C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\remo_app\cmd\postgres.py”, line 55, in _is_installed
self._set_env_vars()
File “C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\remo_app\cmd\postgres.py”, line 91, in _set_env_vars
if not os.path.exists(os.getenv(‘PGDATA’)):
File “C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\genericpath.py”, line 19, in exists
os.stat(path)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Remo. Take a look here:

https://support.remo.ai/

and see there are two threads about installation problems on Windows.

Comment: yes , i also posted the question there they released an update which help me out